# копирование блока на Js

Tags: javascript, html

[image: help]

[image: help]

[image: help]

помогите сделать так, чтобы при нажатии New Question блок Question копировался внизу 
JS HTML

Comment: Код следует выкладывать в виде текста а не скриншотами. Исправьте пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var ddd = document.querySelector('.qqq').cloneNode(true);
 document.body.insertBefore(ddd, document.querySelector('button'));

})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

div {
  color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="qqq"><input type="text" placeholder="Имя"><input type="text" placeholder="фамилия"></div>
<button>добавить</button>
```